# In a view, why does visual studio not know that a semi colon after a model directive is going to cause a runtime error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm very very new to MVC3, and ran in to a problem very soon after going thru the asp.net mvc3 tutorials from pluralsight.

Trying out the strongly typed example of the introduction 'adding a model' section, This works:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.RestaurantReview
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page 1";
}
...
```

But this doesn't... it builds, and then chokes on a runtime error:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.RestaurantReview;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page 1";
}
...
```

The only difference being that semi colon after the @model directive, turning it in to a statement, rather than a directive.

Why doesn't visual studio know that this is going to crash? The error message that IIS presents during the crash isn't even the correct line number of where the error actually is in the code.

VS does underline the line in red, telling me that only such and such can be used in a statement, but it doesn't prevent the build success.

This seems like it would be a nightmare to debug in a big project if it wasn't caught right away, no?

Comment: Doesn't seem that nightmare'y, it can only really happen once per view, and you'll presumably learn eventually not to do it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obviously a bug. We are aware of it and will fix it for the next version of MVC (in fact the fix is already in the MVC 4 Developer Preview).

Comment: is it a bug? I thought it was a feature:s (I meant not blowing up in our faces when an error occurs on one of our views by **feature**)

Answer (score 2):

Compile your views on the build event and it should make your views choked if there is any syntax error.

To make your views to be compiled, please do the following;

1. Unload your project by right right
   clicking the project on the solution
   explorer in VS and clicking unload
   project
2. Right click the project which has
   been converted to unavailable
   project and click "Edit
   your_project_name.csproj" (that
   would be vbproj I guess if your
   project is VB project)
3. See the following code;

   ```
   <!--There some lines of code here and I deleted them to get to the point quickly-->

   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
   ```
4. Change the **MvcBuildViews** node value from `false` to `true`
5. After this action, save it and reload your
   project.

Then, build your solution to compile it. You will see that your views will be compiled as well.

**UPDATE**

Tried your example and it choked as supposed. So it has [Works on My Machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html) Seal of Approval

[image]

**UPDATE**

I have written a quick blog post on this topic. See the details :

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-to-detect-errors-of-our-asp-net-mvc-views-on-compile-time-blow-up-in-my-face-theory